# HTML5 structure label with input OR input IN label

Tags: html, code-structure

which one is more appropriate?

First one:

```
<div>
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
</div>
```

Second one:

```
<label for="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
</label>
```

They're working as well, but i'm not sure if the second option is good with all html structures.

Comment: Either structure is valid and accessible as long as you have the 'for' attribute in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put input inside label like this and wouldn't use outside `div` wrapper:

```
<label for="male">Male
   <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
</label>
```

In this way input gets focus when clicked on the label text `Male`.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are valid HTML per [the w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) and the for isn't mandatory in the second form.

Use whichever you prefer.